# Ruby how to change option on extension that was already activated

Tags: ruby, middleman

Is it possible to change an extension option after you've activated it?  Basically, we have this:

```
activate :dato,
  token: ENV.fetch("DATO_API_TOKEN"), live_reload: true, preview: true

configure :development do
  activate :livereload
end
```

But this sets the `preview: true` option for all environments.  What I'd like to do is move the `preview: true` setting inside the `configure :development` block.

Comment: You could have different `activate` calls for each environment, e.g. `activate :dato, ..., preview: true` in your `development` env and `activate :dato, ..., preview: false` in your `build` env.

Comment: BTW, I think it's "extension" rather than "gem" in Middleman terms.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, I came upon that solution since I posted the question.  The problem is, I have a `dato.tap do |dato|` block that's outside both of the `configure` bocks and it throws an error because `dato` isn't defined yet.  I guess I could move that block inside the `configure` blocks but it would be duplicate code and it's a _big_ block, could increase potential for bugs.

Comment: It's still Ruby. You could wrap the `tap` code in a method or a proc and call it from within `configure`. [Adding Methods to config.rb](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/custom-extensions/#adding-methods-to-config-rb) seems to be the correct way to do that in Middleman. For a more specific answer, you have to show the whole code (i.e. including the `tap` part)

Comment: Ah cool, thanks.  Let me look into how to do that.  Sorry, I'm a total noob, not usually in charge of the Ruby portion of the app.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this solution.  Not sure if it's the best solution but it works.  Note: "ENVIRONMENT" variable is only set for production, so 'development' is defined as lack of the key with value 'production'.

```
activate :dato,
  token: ENV.fetch("DATO_API_TOKEN"), live_reload: true, preview: !(ENV.key?("ENVIRONMENT") && ENV["ENVIRONMENT"] == "production")
```

Comment: `ENV.key?("ENVIRONMENT")` is not even needed. If the key doesn't exist, `ENV["ENVIRONMENT"]` simply returns `nil` which isn't equal to `"production"` either.

Comment: Ok cool, I'll try that out later, would be nice to make the code a little more readable.  However, I believe I remember that it didn't return nil but rather threw an error.  Thanks.

Comment: [`ENV.fetch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/ENV.html#method-c-fetch) does (it raises a KeyError), whereas [`ENV.[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/ENV.html#method-c-5B-5D) merely returns `nil`.